# Show posts in reverse order in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have duplicate the index.php page and called it old.php.
Then I replace the `query_posts();` for `query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );`.
I want to be able to use index.php as the normal wp home page and the old.php to show posts in reverse order. ( think you understand my ideia )
How do I call old.php with pretty urls so visitors can view list of posts in reverse order?

Comment: how about order=DESC?

Comment: yes, it is DESC, just missied on the query.

Comment: NO, **NEVER** use `query_posts`. Rather use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to place it in a separate PHP file? If the only difference between `index.php` and `old.php` is the order of which the posts are displayed, you can just use `index.php` alone, and just pass in the ordering as a parameter:

**index.php**

```
$order = 'DESC';
if (isset($_GET['order']) and $_GET['order'] == 'reversed') {
  $order = 'ASC';
}
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&order=' . $order);
```

This will display the posts in reversed order if your URL looks something like `/index.php?order=reversed` (still looks pretty).

Comment: thanks Arnelle, seems a nice solution for what i need, many thanks !

Comment: NO, **NEVER** use `query_posts`. Rather use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Oh I'm sorry about that, but I don't know any WP stuff so I can't tell which things are good practice and which ones are not. I'm just giving an answer on how it can be done with PHP. It's up to you to use the best practices that you know :)